# Where can I save the cost of private pilot training

Tags: flight-training

I'm a Chinese who want to take private pilot training.

I know there are some personal factors that can reduce the expenses. But Is there any other factors like posistion of the flight school which can save cost? Are some states are generally cheaper than other states?

Comment: What country do you intend on training in, that will vary this answer greatly.

Comment: I prefer the USA of private pilot

Comment: What do you mean by 'personal factors'? Are you only interested in location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One factor is the cost of 100LL fuel, and generally you will find the lowest price for that in Texas and states immediately around it.

Other factor is to choose to do your training in the smallest trainer you can fit into, like a Cessna 15x.

You might also want to consider doing your training somewhere other than in the US. When you get the foreign PPL you can then take the test for the US PPL and apply to convert your license to a US PPL.